# Is my graphic card damaged/dead?

Tags: graphics-card, hardware-failure, ddr3, physical-damage

This morning I booted the PC and I discovered that overnight (no thunders or other electrical variations occurred as far as I know) I got 2 big damages:

1. 2 memory banks dead (G.Skill F3-1600C9D-8GAO)
2. Video card (seem) dead (Sapphire 11196-09-40G AMD Radeon HD7950 3GB)

I tested the RAMs by trial and boot error and they seem to be gone for good, still I'm not 100% sure as I don't have another PC to test them, the system just keep rebooting when I plug one of the faulty one in.

For the video card I tried re-connecting it and I saw what I tried to circle in red, I think is a damage but I'm no electronic expert.
If I try to boot the system with it connected I see no output from the video card and the PC won't continue the boot as the motherboard (Gigabyte GA-Z77X-UD5H) will show the debug error 62.

If I unplug one of the additional power supply cables from the card the system boot but I get no output from it and the mobo show debug 04 or D4, there is no difference between the 2 symbols but they seem to have completely different meanings.

Configuration is/was as follow:

- Gigabyte GA-Z77X-UD5H
- OCZ 600MXSP
- i5-3570K
- G.Skill F3-1600C9D-8GAO x4
- Sapphire 11196-09-40G AMD Radeon HD7950 3GB
- Western Digital WD20EZRX Caviar Green
- Samsung MZ-75E250B SSD 850 EVO 250 GB 2.5" SATA III

Anyone can help me understand the situation?

[image: Sapphire HD 7950 "Vapor X"]

Comment: The white drip to the left of the word HDMI looks a little like a dried precipitate/salt (etc). Have you looked very carefully at any capacitors or batteries that are on the motherboard in the region where the GPU may have gotten splashed? Look for swollen capacitors (they usually have a  "+" shaped score mark on the top so if they fail they won't build too much pressure). Electronics boards often have flux-like residues on them that can capture dust so that drip may be an indication of nothing. Also, don't touch or mess with capacitors, they can have "can kill you" power stored even unplugged

Comment: I wouldn't rule out that your GPU and RAM are actually fine. It's much more likely that your PSU died. Test that first

Comment: Yorik: I'll check the capacitors ASAP, great advice, I had experience with them and I know how to not touch them, thanks!

@jdwolf: I tested the RAMs in different slots, if I plug in any of the two the system will loop restart, about the GPU however, I think is working but I have to test it somewhere, I'm checking with friends/relatives :S
The PSU should't give other problems to the system? Without the GPU the system is working fine, 100% stable even under stress